# Error trying to install "@intercom/intercom-react-native" on ios using react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, intercom

I did the installation as it is in the documentation https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/react-native-installation, but when I run the pod install command it gives the following error:

```
➜  ios git:(master) ✗ pod install 
Using Expo modules
Auto-linking React Native module for target `intercomexpo`: intercom-react-native
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "intercom-react-native":
  In Podfile:
    intercom-react-native (from `../node_modules/@intercom/intercom-react-native`)

Specs satisfying the `intercom-react-native (from `../node_modules/@intercom/intercom-react-native`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: You are using Expo right?

Comment: @YamanKATBY Right, I´m using expo bare workflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of `@intercom/intercom-react-native` (version **2.0.1** at the time of writing) requires iOS 13 or later.

[image]

If the iOS project in your React Native app has its deployment target set to **anything below iOS 13.0**, you'll get the following error when you run `pod install`:

```sh
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "intercom-react-native"
```

The solution is to drop back to the previous version.

If using NPM:

```sh
npm install @intercom/intercom-react-native@1.1.1
```

If using Yarn:

```sh
yarn add @intercom/intercom-react-native@1.1.1
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In the `Podfile` change the value to `13.0`

`platform :ios, '13.0'`

Note: Changing the deployment target in xCode is not sufficient.

Comment: also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76983245/4986116