# Unable to Pod Install on a brand new React Native Project

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

I am running on an M1 Mac, and after following all of the instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), I am unable to run any form of `pod install`. When I do, I am given the following error...

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method
`min_ios_version_supported' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x000000010ed18c60>.
```

I've tried running `bundle install` followed by `bundle exec pod install`, but I am faced then with the same error.

I use yarn instead of npm, I've tried removing the `node_modules` and running `yarn cache clean` as per some other answer on this site, though I did not truly expect those to work.

Additionally, my `Podfile` does contain the needed imports at the top of the file...

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

I've even tried to just manually enter a `min_ios_version_supported` at `12.4` because that is what my most recent project is working on. That gave me a different error, which I fixed again with a manual value entry, but that gave me a different more complicated error, essentially telling me I am better off actually solving the issue instead of patching it.

Finally, I've tried adding the `react-native.config.js` file. Still receiving the same error

I've made plenty of React Native projects before, and noticed that this `Podfile` on my brand new project looks very different than `Podfile`s I've used in the past-- am I on a new version of React that is not yet optimized?

Comment: Your RN version should be 0.71.1 in your package.json, is it?

Comment: It was initially, I tried rolling it back to 0.69 but it provided the same error. Something must have gone wrong with the project's initialization, I just abandoned it and started from scratch again

Comment: It has to be 71.1 to have the right scripts for the Podfile.

Comment: Starting with RN 0.71, the supported iOS version is no longer directly defined in Podfile. This simplifies the setup by allowing RN to manage the supported version. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/34fafb2b881751cdd998d7d5ef486d536607c9ce

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At Podfile, *min_ios_version_supported* is in

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
```

So, in *'../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'*, you change at line 29:

```
def min_ios_version_supported
  return '12.4'
end
```

to

```
def min_ios_version_supported
  return '13.0'
end
```

After that, delete Podfile.lock, Pods and ***pod install***
again!

Good luck!

Comment: This happened to me after RN upgrade to 0.71.3 using Upgrade Helper. I just ran npm install and after that i ran: npx pod-install

Comment: This is not the right answer. The files in the node-modules directory are controlled by npm. Any changes you make there will be overwritten the next time you run `npm i`.

Comment: @Jon this is the temp fix (hot fix) because of upgrading new RN, for a long time RN fixed this bug.

Comment: I agree with @Jon, I've removed the variable and just hard-coded the value to '13'

Answer (score 8):

I do not really like the idea to change something in `node_modules` folder.
Just try to use this approach:

```
min_ios_versions_supported = ['13.0', min_ios_version_supported]
index_of_max = min_ios_versions_supported.each_with_index.max_by { |number, _| number.to_f }[1]
platform :ios, min_ios_versions_supported[index_of_max]
```

You may set any your `min_ios_version_supported (here '13.0')` and `min_ios_version_supported (from RN)` as is. Then just choose the max of them. Profit!

Comment: Yep nice solution!
If react-native required a newer version, it will take that automatically.

Thx

Answer (score 6):

can't we just replace `Podfile` with this?

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

The `min_ios_version_supported` is a managed property that depends on the version of `react-native` and changing it with hard coding can cause issues later on depending on your development environment.

If you need version `13.0`, just specify it in your `Podfile`.

Answer (score 3):

In My Case, It worked after I moved below two lines to the top of the Podfile.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing those "require" statements, and that was the reason why the "min_ios_version_supported" variable was not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, in my case, I wanted to upgrade react native to 0.71.4 and I changed that manually in `package.json`. The error happened when I tried `pod install` before running `yarn install`.

Running `yarn install` and only then `pod install` fixed the issue for me. Hope this helps somebody.